# Python - Efficiently working with large permutated lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, permutation, python-itertools, anagram

I've written a short **Anagram Solver** script in **Python 2.7**.

```
#Import Permutations Module
from itertools import permutations as perm

#Defined Functions
def check(x,y):

    #Opens Dictionary File
    with open('wordsEn.txt') as dictionary:

        '''Checks the permutations against all of the dictionary words and appends
        any matching ones to on of the empty lists'''

        for line in dictionary:
            for i in x:
                if i + '\n' == line:
                    y.append(i)

#Empty Lists that will be appended to later
anagram_perms = []
possible_words = []

#Anagram User Input
anagram = list(raw_input("Input scrambled word: ").lower())

#Creates single list items from the permutations, deletes duplicates
for char in perm(anagram):
    anagram_perms.append("".join(char))
    anagram_perms = list(set(anagram_perms))

#Uses the defined function
check(anagram_perms, possible_words)

#Prints the number of perms created, then prints the possible words beneath it
print len(anagram_perms)
print '\n'.join(possible_words)
```

It essentially takes a user inputted anagram, generates and places into a list all possible combinations of the letters (using `itertools.permutations`), deleting any duplicates. It then checks each of these of combinations against a 100000 word dictionary text file, placing any matching words into a list to be printed.

I've run into the issue that if a user inputs a word that is above 6 unique letters in length, the number of permutations generated causes hanging and crashes. 9 letter anagrams would be the typical input, however evidently these will output **362880** ('9!') permutations if all letters are different, which is unfeasible.

I've though about a couple of **potential solutions**:

1. Creating a number of empty lists which can only hold a certain number of appended permuations. Once these lists are 'full', permutations are added to the next one. Each of these lists are then subsequently checked against the text file.
2. Creating one empty list contained within a loop. Permutations are generated and appened to the list up to a certain workable number, the list is then used to check the text file before emptying itself and appending in the next number of permutations.
3. Some other method whereby a certain number of permutations are generated, then the process is paused while the currently generated ones are checked against the text file, and resumed and repeated.

I'm fairly new to Python development however and don't really know if these would be possible or how I would go about implementing them into my code; and other questions on similar topics haven't really been able to help.

If anyone would like to see my code so far I'd be happy to condense it down and post it, but for the sake of not making this question any longer I'll leave it out unless it's requested. **(Updated Above)**

Thanks!

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Please post your code, brief info of what your code does(BRIEF), sample input, and required output (or the issue you are facing). Else no one is going to read this much, or if someone does it is problamatic for them to understand. Please help us to help you :)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri , I wasn't sure if the benefits of adding the code but increasing the length of the question would be worth it and encourage people to read, but sure thing, I'll get on condensing and adding it :)

Comment: StackOverflow community helps you to resolve your issue, but we also need to see the efforts you made in order to resolve it.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Alright thanks, updated above :)

Answer (score 1):

It think the best solution may be to not use permutations. It's much more likely than not that most generated permutations are not a word - so it's a waste to generate them all.

You can consider pre-processing this dictionary to a dictionary of sorted letters to list of words that those letters consist of. Then, your anagram solver will be a simple lookup in a dictionary after sorting the input.

First, create the dictionary from your word list and save to a file:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json

word_list = ['tab', 'bat', 'cat', 'rat', ...]  # 100k words
word_dict = defaultdict(list)
for word in word_list:
    word_dict[''.join(sorted(word))].append(word)
with open('word_dict.json') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(dict(word_dict)))
```

Then, when running your anagram code, load the dictionary and use it to look up the sorted input:

```
import json

empty_list = []
with open('word_dict.json', 'r') as f:
    word_dict = json.loads(f.read())

while True:
    anagram = raw_input('Enter in an anagram: ')
    sorted_anagram = ''.join(sorted(anagram))
    print word_dict.get(sorted_anagram, empty_list)
```

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't considered looking at it that way thank you! I don't think this is exactly what you're saying, but it's made me wonder... Could I simply write code that looks at each line of the dictionary text file, and says 'if this line contains all of the inputted anagram's letters once in any order, then append it to the possible_words list, else move to the next line'?

Comment: Yes, but it would be slower than the dictionary approach since you'll have to iterate through the dictionary and count letters through each loop iteration.

Comment: True. So, correct me if I've got this wrong, you're saying first get the length of the inputted anagram and use it to put all words of the same length from the text file into a dictionary, then check to see which ones of those words have the same letters as the anagram and append them to a list? :) Would you mind adding a couple of comments to your code as there are one or two things that I think I'm not quite understanding about it?

Comment: Ah sorry, I think my limited knowledge of python isn't helping here and I'm still not understanding it properly. The 100k words list is a .txt file, are you saying that I should append them all into list (word_list) first and then go on from there? And what is the benefit of importing the `json` module?

Comment: The suggestion would be to take your .txt file, and do a one-time conversion of this file to a different .json file which contains the dictionary I described. Then, you should use this .json file instead of your .txt file. The `json` module helps you serialize and deserialize the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.  The `itertools.permutations` function returns an iterator.  This means that the entire list is not stored in memory; rather you can call for the next value and it will compute what is needed on the fly.

```
from itertools import permutations

with open('./wordlist.txt', 'r') as fp:
    wordlist_str = fp.read()
    wordlist = set(wordlist_str.lower().split('\n'))  #use '\r\n' in Windows

def get_anagrams(word):
    out = set()
    for w in permutations(word.lower()):
        if ''.join(w) in wordlist:
            out.add(''.join(w))
    return out
```